# On-topicness question

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

This is just to discuss the on-topicness of [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/56875/52087).

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 3):

The on-topicness is questionable. You make little to no case about how the theorem relates to the UI in question on Maya's screen.

The Riemann zeta-function is about reciprocal derivatives. It's representation here is within 3 dimension, with color representing depth.

You question may be more on-topic if it were worded more in regards to what inspired the interface design than assuming it had something to do with the Riemann zeta-function, besides the fact that they seem similar.

We cannot migrate this question because such a topic is not on-topic with any of the math-related SE sites. Please consider rephrasing your question to me more in scope with the aesthetic design rather than any mathematical theorems that you believe it may represent (you may still mention it in passing, but it should not be the main focus as it will skew the topic towards it rather that what inspired the design).

Comment: I've decided to delete the question. I had already mentioned the similarity with the function was something out of my imagination, so I thought I'd might as well to delete the original question. If someone is interested I might consider reopening it, but currently I don't feel any interest in dedicating effort to it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The question *could* be on-topic if the UI in question is *really* showing the Riemann zeta function. I believe the question would be then also on-topic under [symbolism](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism).

However, since the current premise is very weak that even the OP later doubt themself, it is hard to assume if the current wording is on-topic.